# Path Connected in Topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the set of $2\times2$ complex matrices with determinant 1 is path connected.
I know if I want to show that I have to show $\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & \beta  \\ 0 & \gamma  \end{array} \right]$ can be connected to $\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1  \end{array} \right]$ .
I do not know how prove it?

Answer (score 2):

That's not too hard: Find a path in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ from $\alpha$ to $1$ (and of course $\beta$ to $0$ in $\mathbb C$) and use that $z\mapsto \frac 1z$ is continuous.

As a sidenote: How did you connect an arbitrary $\det 1$ matrix to an upper triangular one?

Comment: I know that I have to find $ \alpha & \beta & \gamma from [0,1] to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha(0)=\alpha & \alpha(10)=1$ and other as well. but I do not know?

Comment: could you explain more please? and edit my note

Comment: About your question, it is Lemma in liner Algebra